# oci_connect fails from command line but works in browser

Tags: php, oracle, command-line

I wrote a PHP script to run as a cron job and it wasn't running.  The script worked fine in the browser, but I discovered when I ran it from the command line that I got this error:

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in /usr/apps/webdata/cron/PropogateDB.php on line 190
```

The line in question is:

```
$conn_NRB = oci_connect($user, $pass, "nrb.njbbnrbpd1");
```

As I said this script works fine in the browser.

I did some digging around and found the configuration settings for the database.  I then tried this:

```
$conn_NRB = oci_connect($user, $pass, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=nrb)))");
```

With this code both the command line and the browser give me this error:

```
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied in /usr/apps/webdata/cron/PropogateDB.php on line 191
```

As far as I know there are no other usernames and passwords that I can use.  (I'm trying to verify that now.)

I searched around on this site and discovered someone else with a similar problem, although his problem was reversed, and his cause was that the command line and the browser pointed to two different php.ini files.  I just confirmed that both the browser and the command line invoke the same php.ini file.  They both point to:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php/lib
```

Is there any other reason why a script would work in the browser but fail in the command line?  I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and I don't have direct access to the database so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 'EasyConnect' string

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=nrb)))
```

refers to localhost. 'In the browser' likely means: *on the server* (where the PHP script executes).

Unless you run the test on the command - line *of the same server*, you should change the connect string to refer to the Database server (which might be simply the host name of your web-server).

Beware of firewall restrictions that may come in the way. Prefer to use your company's `tnsnames.ora` to resolve database instances identifiers to their connect strings, if possible.

Comment: The command line and browser are both connected to the same machine.

I tried changing "localhost" to "nrb.njbbnrbpd1" and it was unable to resolve the connection.  (There might be a different name I have to use.  I'm not sure.)

Comment: @user1672174 The point is that the browser doesn't execute the PHP. The server does (look at the address bar). And that will likely not be the same machine

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the same machine.  The address of the script in the browser is http://nrbdev/cron/PropogateDB.php.  When I connect via PuTTY I type "nrbdev" into the Host Name field.  I can then navigate via the command line to /usr/apps/webdata/cron, do a directory listing, and see PropogateDB.php listed there.  Unless I'm missing something it's the same machine.  However, this does give me a thought.  If the database was on a different machine localhost would fail, right?  Would it still work via the browser with the code above if that was the case?